# How to insert records in external database with objective-C

Tags: iphone, mysql, xcode, insert

I have a question, want to make an application to insert records in an external database, but does not work.
Does anyone help me?
This is my xCode code:

```
-(IBAction)enviar:(id)sender
{
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.37/mysql_iphone/insertar_alumno.php?nombre=%@&poblacion=%@",cajaNombre.text,cajaPoblacion.text];
    NSData *dataUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",strResult);
}
```

and this, is my php code

```php
 <?php
   //Credenciales de la BBDD
   $db = "iphone";
   $host = 'localhost';
   $username = "dpbataller";
   $password = '1234';

   //Conectamos al servidor de la Base de datos
   $link = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("No se puede conectar");
   //Seleccionamos la BBDD
   @mysql_select_db($db) or die ("No se ha podido seleccionar a la base de datos");

   //Creamos un array para almacenar los resultados
   $arr = array();

   //Recogemos los valores
   //$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
   //$poblacion = $_POST['poblacion'];
   //Lanzamos la consulta
   $consulta = mysql_query("INSERT INTO alumnos (id,nombre,poblacion)  VALUES  ('','$_POST[nombre]','$_POST[poblacion]')";

   ?>
```

and this is the message of Xcode console:

```
2012-04-26 23:04:44.981 parse[902:f803] <br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in     <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysql_iphone/insertar_alumno.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Missing closing parenthesis on `mysql_query()` function on last line of PHP code.

Comment: oh yeah! It works! :)
but the record is blank in the database. What happens?

Comment: If the `id` column is an auto-increment field, don't pass in blank. Try `mysql_query("INSERT INTO alumnos (nombre,poblacion)  VALUES  ('$_POST[nombre]','$_POST[poblacion]')");`

Answer (score 0):

$consulta = mysql_query("INSERT INTO alumnos (id,nombre,poblacion)  VALUES  ('','$_POST['nombre']','$_POST['poblacion']')";

Comment: This question was already answered in the comments of the question. I think it is a good practice to sum the results of a commentary discussion up in a comprehensive answer. You could have added a little more explanation.