# Explanation of NSMutableURLRequest : setHTTPMethod

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, xcode, post

I am new to objective c programming. I am currently trying to insert data into mysql database. I have read a couple links on this and could not find the exact answer I am looking for.

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have my app that user inputs a name in a text field and once the press the add button, it makes a connection to my php file and my php file does the rest of the work (using POST method) and adds the name to the mysql dataase.

I have seen a lot of people use ``` NSMutableURLRequest : setHTTPMethod :POST`` in their code (in my case my php file does that and I don't have ```NSMutableURLRequest` included in my code and it works perfectly fine.)

My questions are:

- Are there any benefits of including `NSMutableURLRequest` in your code when you can just call your php code to take care of the POST for you?
- What does `NSMutableURLRequest` exactly do and which way is more efficient?

Here is to rephrase my question:

Would it be better to connect to the php file using the following NSMutableRequest method:

```
NSString *loginString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fn_checkLogin2.php?name=%@&pass=%@", self.email.text, self.password.text];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myworkingdomain.com/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url ];

[urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:30.0f];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[loginString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSOperationQueue *queue= [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
    if ([data length]>0 && error==nil) {
        NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"HTML = %@",html);
    }
}
 ];
```

OR this way:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myworkingdomain.com/fn_checkLogin2.php?name=%@&pass=%@", self.email.text, self.password.text];

// to execute php code
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

// to receive the returend value
NSString *strResult = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutableurlrequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for the link but I have updated the question above please see if it makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: It does, I was just trying to help with "what exactly does xxx function do"? :)

Answer (score 2):

`NSMutableURLRequest` creates a HTTP request that will be sent to a URL.

Every HTTP request must have a "method", which can be one of:

- GET
- HEAD
- POST
- PUT
- DELETE
- TRACE
- OPTIONS
- CONNECT
- PATCH

GET is the default and will be used if you don't specify anything. Almost all HTTP requests are GET. It's intended to be used when you fetch data from the server.

POST is pretty much the only other method that is used commonly, it's intended to be used when you send data to the server.

The main reason to use POST is to disable caching. If you send a GET request to the same URL twice, sometimes the second request will not send anything at all to the server, it will just respond with whatever the first response sent back.

This caching can be done at any stage in the request, for example most web browsers will do it, and some ISPs will do it too. The last one is the biggest problem, since it will only happen on users who are with one of those ISPs. It can also be done by the server, for example my PHP code will often save GET responses to the disk and return the contents of that file next time a request for the same URL hits my PHP script, reducing server load significantly. I don't do this for POST requests.

So, if you want the request to definitely be sent to the server you should always set the request method to POST.

Comment: So what is the different between using POST in your php file vs. having it in your code, because I can still successfully connect to my php file and have it do all the work without having to include the NSMutableURLRequest in my code (that is how i am doing it now)

Comment: There isn't any significant difference. All it does is change a string "GET" to "POST" which has very little impact at all on how PHP operates. However if you do not use POST, sometimes the HTTP request will *never be sent to the server at all*. It's very hard to reproduce, you have to be using an ISP that caches GET requests, and most of them do not do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think you are getting what I am asking. I have updated my question above see if it makes more sense.

Comment: @kkmoslehpour I think I understand your question. The second one will use GET as the request method. This means that sometimes the "fn_checkLogin2.php" page will not be loaded at all, it will just silently return a cached version of the URL, without any way for you to know when it does that. You need to use POST, not GET, so you need to use NSMutableURLRequest.

Comment: So you are saying even though my php code specifies to use POST method it will still use the GET method to retrieve values? For example how this guy did it. he did not use the POST method in the code, but uses it in his php file.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341442/how-to-insert-records-in-external-database-with-objective-c

Comment: @kkmoslehpour yes. I have been doing Obj-C for 12 years and PHP for 10 years, both as my day job. There is no way $_POST works in that code you linked to. He must have changed it to $_GET. The request method is chosen by the obj-c code. by the time PHP starts executing it is far too late to change over to POST.